# add more than one worksheet to excel using for loops

Tags: excel, vba

```
For j = 1 To UniqueItems(ActiveSheet.Range(TrN_col & "2:" & TrN_col & LastTrN), True)
    With Workbook
        Worksheets.Add().Name = UniqueItems(ActiveSheet.Range(TrN_col & "2:" & TrN_col & LastTrN), False)(j)
    End With
Next j
```

`UniqueItems()` is a function that returns the number of unique items in a column as an array.  currently with the data i'm working with there are two unique items in the column. if I use the `MsgBox()` function I get two unique items as I should. Which makes me think that the subroutine is somehow escaped after a new worksheet is added.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** 
In other words how do I get excel to activate the most recently created worksheet?

Comment: What exactly is your question? And pasting your full code -ie the `UniqueItems` function will enable us to test any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new sheet, it becomes the active sheet. After you iterate once.... you will be evaluating `uniqueitems` on an emptyworksheet.

I would refactor `uniqueitems` to return a collection or dictionary instead of what you are doing.

Results would look a something like:

```
Dim list as Dictionary

set list = UniqueItems(ActiveSheet.Range(TrN_col & "2:" & TrN_col & LastTrN))

For each key in list.keys
  worksheets.add().name = key
next
```